# Details on matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

For **Ax** = **b**,

**b** is a linear combination of the columns of **A**. **A** scales **x**.

However, for **AB**, assuming both have suitable sizes, which matrix acts on which? Is there a linear combination of some sort going on? How do the columns/rows interact with each other? For example, 2x2 matrices.

Comment: $A$ acts on the columns of $B$, since that is how you have matrix multiplication defined. Note that $AB = \begin{bmatrix} Ab_{1} & Ab_{2} & \cdots \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: So a correct phrasing would be " **A** acts on the columns of **B**. Is there a more detailed definition? Do rows of **A** act on columns of **B**? Or is it not so simple?

Comment: No, the matrix $A$ transforms the columns of $B$ just like in $Ax=b$, the matrix $A$ acts on the vector $x$.

Comment: The convention (under your definition) has matrices acting from the left on column vectors.

Comment: @MorganRodgers thanks! I managed to solve the problem that resulted in this question. Are there other definitions under alternative conventions?

Comment: Sure, you could define vectors to be rows and then define matrix multiplication as $xA$ giving the linear combination of the rows of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a linear space $V$ and $W$ over a field $F$ (for example $V$ can be the vector space $\mathbb R^n$ where $F=\mathbb R$), a **linear map** is a function $f: V \to W$ such that for all $\mathbf v, \mathbf w \in V$ and $a \in F$, $$f(a\mathbf v+\mathbf w)=af(\mathbf v)+f(\mathbf w).$$

A matrix $\mathbf A$ is a linear map that takes a vector "$\mathbf v$" and returns a vector "$\mathbf{Av}$". In fact all linear functions can be defined like that, so we don't distinguish a matrix and a linear function.

Matrix multiplication is just function composition. It is defined as $\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{A\circ B}$. In other words, it is defined so that $\mathbf{A(Bv)}=\mathbf{(AB)v}$ for all $\mathbf{v}$.

---

To prove that all linear map can be written as a matrix, we can write any vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ as a linear combination of the basis $\{\mathbf{e_1,e_2,e_3,...e_n}\}$ of $V$:
$$
\mathbf{v}=v^1\mathbf{e_1}+v^2\mathbf{e_2} ... v^n\mathbf{e_n}
$$

(the superscripts are indices, not powers)

(A basis is a set of $n$ non-zero vectors in a $n$ dimensional vector space that are linearly independent, i.e. cannot be written as a linear combination of other vectors in the set.)

At the same time, we can define $\{\mathbf{e'_1, e'_2,...e'_m}\}$ to be a basis of $W$.

A linear map $f: V \to W$ applied by $v$ can be written as
$$
f(\mathbf v)= v^1 f(\mathbf {e_1}) + v^2 f(\mathbf {e_2}) + ... + v^n f(\mathbf {e_n}).
$$

But we can write
$$
f(\mathbf{e}_k)=w^1{}_k\mathbf{e'_1}+w^2{}_k\mathbf{e'_2}+...+w^m{}_k\mathbf{e'_m}
$$
therefore
$$
f(\mathbf{v}) = \sum_k\sum_j w^j{}_k v^k \mathbf{e'_j}
$$
If we see $\{v^k\}$ as a representation of $\mathbf v$, and the $\{w^j{}_k\}$, a table of $m\times n$ numbers, is a complete description of $f$.

---

Given $f: U\to V$ and $g: V \to W$, and
$$
f(\mathbf e_i)= \sum_j a^j{}_i \mathbf e'_j
$$
$$
g(\mathbf e'_j)= \sum_k b^k{}_j \mathbf e''_k
$$
then
$$\begin{align*}
g(f(\mathbf e_i)) &= g\left(\sum_j a^j{}_i \mathbf e'_j\right) \\
&= \sum_j a^j{}_i g(\mathbf e'_j) \\
&= \sum_j a^j{}_i \sum_k b^k{}_j \mathbf e''_k \\
&= \sum_k \sum_j a^j{}_i b^k{}_j \mathbf e''_k \\
\end{align*}$$

Therefore we can use $\left\{w^k{}_i=\sum_ja^j{}_i b^k{}_j\right\}$ to represent the linear mapping $g\circ f$.